# is there way to we can validate a pipeline file before jenkins starts executing the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to ensure that a particular stage is not skipped from a JenkinsFile. For example i would like to ensure that dev has not skipped the Code scanning in the pipeline. This should happen before the pipeline is executed by Jenkins.

I could manually check this via looking for the "Test Results" on the page that I have included the image for below. This indicates that the job has published Test Results to the JUnit plugin.

[image]

If I were to write a Jenkinsfile, it might look something like this. But it is possible to attach these to the JUnit pipeline via manual methods as well:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps { 
                // Login to Repository
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'nexus_maven_configuration', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS compile'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') { 
            steps { 
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'nexus_maven_configuration', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS test'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
            archive 'target/*.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a global boolean that is only set to true if the end of the code scanning stage was reached and validate that later.

Comment: If you give full control to Jenkinsfile to dev, there is no way you can restrict it. but If you write a generic shared library and ask them to just use the library on their Jenkisfile ..you can control whatever you want.